# Use the tab key for Mac OS X Spotlight?

Tags: macos, spotlight

As the title goes, how can I use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to cycle through Spotlight suggestions, instead of arrow keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Karabiner`](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en).

### Steps:

1. edit and save the `private.xml` file, you can find the file in `Misc & Uninstall` panel of `Krabiner`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
       <appdef>
           <appname>SPOTLIGHT</appname>
           <equal>com.apple.Spotlight</equal>
       </appdef>

       <item>
           <name>Use Tab instead Up in Spotlight</name>
           <identifier>private.spotlight.tab</identifier>
           <only>SPOTLIGHT</only>
           <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP</autogen>
           <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::TAB, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN</autogen>
       </item>
   </root>
   ```
2. Then make sure you check the `Use Tab instead Up in Spotlight` item after you `Reload XML` in `Change Key` panel.

It should works now.

Comment: thanks! But I wasn't entirely sure where to put this code, I tried creating another file `spotlight.xml` and include this file in `private.xml`, the new item didn't pop up after reload, also, putting this directly in `private.xml`, neither does that work, could you teach a little more?

Comment: @timfeirg just updated & hope it helps.